# How to change user logged token and reload it

Tags: symfony

I'm in troble trying to get the token from already user logged and update it. I'm using a custom token extending UsernamePasswordToken.

The following code is placed in an action method.

```
...
$token = $this->get('security.context')->getToken();
$token->setContact($contact);
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
...
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('public_homepage'));
```

After this, dumping the token shows that the token has been updated.

My problem is, after redirecting, a voter has to check the contact. After some checks, when I dump the token received the contact is not set. I placed many logs and I'm very sure that the set is placed before the voter.

Any help please? Thanks!

UPDATE - Adding firewalls config

```
firewalls:
dev:
  pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
  security: false
private:
  pattern: ^/backend
  context: "%firewall_context%"
  anonymous: ~
  access_denied_url: /backend/login
  logout:
    path: /backend/logout
    target: /backend/login
  remember_me:
    key: asdAsda43
    name: asdasdcooas34
    lifetime: 3600 # in seconds  
  form_login:
    check_path: /backend/login_check
    login_path: /backend/login
    use_referer: true

public:
  anonymous: ~
  access_denied_url: /login
  pattern: ^/
  context: "%firewall_context%"
  logout:
    path: /logout
    target: /
  remember_me:
    key: asdAsda43
    name: asdasdcooas34
    lifetime: 3600 # in seconds  
  form_login:
    check_path: /login_check
    login_path: /login
    use_referer: true
```

Comment: Is the public_homepage route using the same firewall as the action you set some extra data to the token? Include your security.yml config

Comment: I have 2 differents firewalls but both use the same context, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How does your setContact method work? Does it set the $contact object (or whatever the $contact is) on the user field of the token? Check out UsernamePasswordToken and AbstractToken classes serialize() methods. If you didn't implement your own serialize(), then it's possible the value is not serialized.